# Is it okay to add DOM Elements with Javascript to create the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In PHP, you can `include` other files (such as a header or footer file - I'll call them *partials*) to help serve the specific page - which allows for a minimal amount of inconsistencies within pages. However, HTML does not have this feature. I've implemented a solution whereby the JavaScript at the end of the page adds the static partials after the document has announced it is ready:

```
$(function() {
  html = "<div id=\"navbar\"><h1>Cool Webpage!</h1></div>";
  $("#header").append(html);
});
```

The `#header` is a `<div>` which is the uppermost portion of the `<header>` - it's used as the target node where the `#navbar` will be injected into.

As far as I can see, this is a feasible workaround to mitigate inconsistencies across pages, but I feel like I'm being a bit too naive.

**Is this method okay to implement, or is there a better way? Could I AJAX in the HTML to add, and still add it on the fly? Are there any issues I should watch out for if implementing this method?**

Comment: Appending elements is just fine, and is used by most sites on the web in some way. However, creating an entire website that way is generally not recommended, separation of concerns and everything !

Comment: In addition to what @adeneo said, consider what would happen in a slow network scenario.  Do you really want your navbars loading late?

Comment: Have a look at Angular. Among other features, it provides support for partial views.

Comment: Same for [ReactJS](http://facebook.github.com/react), it provides support for create components with state support, it's pretty awesome.

Comment: Actually html **does** have a sort of `include`.  It's one of the foundations of [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/).  It's just not super supported yet.  Check out [WebComponents](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)  The syntax is `<link rel="import" href="your_import.html">`

Comment: youtube's spfjs does exactly for that purpose.